# Not receiving Firebase Cloud Messaging Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Xamarin to create a Simple Android Application that receives Push Notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I Followed [Xamarin's Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/) to implement this function.

And followed it step by step until the section that reads:

> [Background Notifications](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Background_Notifications)

I tapped the Log Token Button and  received the token.

The [next step](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Send_a_Message) is to send the notification from Firebase Console, but the notification never gets to the emulator after sending it and no error is logged on Firebase nor the Xamarin console.

The Firebase console displays the message as 'Completed'.

What am I missing to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you add the Token when composing the message in FCM?

Comment: Yes, It was copied from the Xamarin Log and added in Firebase.

Comment: Could you share the demo that you made through online repository?

Comment: Does it occur both when the app is on foreground and background?

Comment: Turns out it worked when running on the background, @AL answer this and I'll mark as answered and upvote

Comment: @JorgeCuevas Cool. I'll add it in. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Messages sent from the Firebase Notifications console are treated as `notification`-only message payloads (unless you add in a custom key-value pair, then it becomes a `notification` and `data` together).

`notification`-only message payload behavior is when the app is in background, the Android System will handle the notification. See [Handling Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) for Android for more details on the behavior.