# Notification in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I open the app and send notification from the Firebase console , the `onMessageReceived` works fine. *The app has its small icon , Notification sound ,etc..* But when the app is killed or is closed , no notification sound or a small icon appears.

Comment: have you followed this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?

Comment: Follow this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase) you will have what you needed.

Comment: Please Refer this link.It may help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969637/android-firebase-push-notification-not-working-when-application-is-killed/44971894#44971894)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not receiving Firebase Cloud Messaging Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178957/not-receiving-firebase-cloud-messaging-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

After GCM the google changed the GCM as FCM, And FCM are containing two type of payload one is `Notification`  and another One is `Data payload` when you are posting notification with Notification Payload then app will be in background then onMessageReceived  not called but when in foreground onMessageReceived  called, But if you put Data payload then all-time onMessageReceived  is called.

**Using Notification Payload**

onMessageReceived called in the only foreground not in background

**Using Data Payload**

onMessageReceived  called every time